# How to use `addMP3PlayerListener` with JACo MP3 player library

Tags: java, mp3

I am trying to create an automatic radio station using the JACo MP3 library.  I have code to generate a random hour long playlist, and I can get JACo MP3 to play it no problem.  What I need to do is somehow get JACo to notify me when the playlist has completed playing so that I can then generate a new hour long playlist and start playing the new list. 
I think I need to use the method "addMP3PlayerListener" method, but don't know how to.

Right now my playlist will play, then the program just sits there.

Here is the code I have:

```
private void startStationActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
{
  boolean isStopped = true;
  while(isStopped)
  {
    int djID = getCurrentDjID();
    DiskJockey dj = new DiskJockey();

    songListing = SongOpenedController.getSongList();

    ArrayList<Song> theCurrentDJsSongs = dj.getDjPlayList(songListing, djID);
    clearTable();
    updateTable(theCurrentDJsSongs);

    MP3Player myPlayer = new MP3Player();
    for (Song song : theCurrentDJsSongs)
    { 
      myPlayer.addToPlayList(new File(song.getSongPathName()));
    }

    myPlayer.play();

    isStopped = myPlayer.isStopped();
  }// end while
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need addMP3PlayerListener(). It's surprisingly simple, actually.

All you need to do is check if the music is stopped (myPlayer.isStopped()) and do it then.

Ryan